# On iOS13 (with Xcode11) get Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException when trying to present RPSystemBroadcastPickerView

Tags: ios13, xcode11, replaykit, rpsystembroadcastpickerview

While presenting **RPSystemBroadcastPickerView** on **iOS 13**, it shows an exception with the following description: Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Application tried to present UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl to or from non-fullscreen view controller .
I am using Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504). Is there any solution to stop this exception?

Comment: Are you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Not yet. Still looking for the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is because iOS 13 uses a new presentation style instead of the full screen. And it doesn't support the PartialCurl transition you need to change the default presentation style:

var navigationController = new UINavigationController(ctrl);
navigationController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
ctrl.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.PartialCurl;
PresentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, null);

Comment: Can you elaborate more with ReplayKit as OP asked?